# how to change image source when you click on it from the list of the images you append through api and json

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $img = 0;    
var arraySrc=[];     

var main = function () {    
    var i = 0;   
    var url = "myurl";   
    $.getJSON(url, function (Response) {  
         flickrResponse.items.forEach(function (photo) {   
             $img = $('<img />', { id: 'img' + i, rc: photo.media.m, alt: 'MyAlt' });    
             var queryData = {src:$img.attr('src')}       
             arraySrc.push(queryData);       
             $("main .photos").append($img);
             i++;
         }); 

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Share HTML as well Provide complete detail

Comment: `"arraySrc[i].src"` is a string literal, if you want to access a variable's value, use `arraySrc[i].src` (*no quotes*).